# Удалить выбранные элементы

Tags: vue.js

Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Есть метод, который должен удалять выбранные позиции в корзине, если они отмечены чекбоксом. Но что-то идет не так. Точнее я понимаю что - пытаюсь удалить по индексу, после каждого цикла индекс у объектов меняется,следовательно идет некорректное удаление. Как можно побороть?

```
deletePosition() {
            for(let i = 0; i < this.listProducts.length; i++) {
                if(this.listProducts[i].checkbox === true) {
                    this.listProducts.splice(this.listProducts[i], 1);
                }
            }
        }
```

Значение чекбокса (true или false) записывается в объекте, поэтому идет сравнение по этому элементу

```
listProducts: [
                {
                    name: 'Нож складной WENGER Evolution ,"Автобус" ,13 функций, 85 мм.WENGER',
                    checkbox: true,
                    image: require('./assets/product1.png'),
                    price: 400,
                    count: 10,
                    sum: 0,
                    showPopup: false
                },
                {
                    name: 'Рюкзак WENGER «NEO»',
                    checkbox: false,
                    image: require('./assets/product2.png'),
                    price: 200,
                    count: 3,
                    sum: 0,
                    showPopup: false
                },
                {
                    name: 'Перьевая ручка Waterman Hemisphere Essential, перо: нержавеющая сталь. WATERMAN',
                    checkbox: true,
                    image: require('./assets/product3.png'),
                    price: 600,
                    count: 1,
                    sum: 0,
                    showPopup: false
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.listProducts = this.listProducts.filter(item => !item.checked)
```

Comment: фильтры вроде во второй версии убрали же

Comment: Из js? Сомневаюсь)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую) Не так давно за JS взялся. Не знал про filter в object

Comment: filter это метод массива, в данном случае this.listProducts, не объекта.

Comment: Вот обновил, показал как выглядит listProducts

Comment: Ну так и есть, массив объектов.

Comment: Извиняюсь за глупые вопросы.
А почему так неправильно? В параметрах же мы указываем по какому массиву проходимся и условие
this.listProducts = this.listProducts.filter(this.listProducts, this.listProducts.checkbox == true)

Comment: У функии filter есть определенная сигнатура: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter Т.е. в качестве аргумента она принимает функцию. То что вы написали, не понятно.